# Change code push deployment key React native

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

While integrating code-push in my react-native app using [code-push tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push), i ran following command:

`react-native link react-native-code-push`

It asked for deployment keys then, which i pasted but now i want to change those keys.

I tried to unlink with the following command but its not working,

`react-native unlink react-native-code-push`

Can someone please guid me, as i'm new to both react-native and code push?

Comment: Is this for Android or iOS? I'm may only able to help with the iOS side of things which is why I ask.

Comment: @Dan it's for both, so you can help regarding IOS only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For IOS:

#### file:

> list.info

#### key:

> CodePushDeploymentKey

## For Android:

#### file:

> strings.xml

#### key:

> reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey

update values of these keys and it will work :)

Comment: How do we add multiple deployment keys for our different environments? E.g Staging, Testing, etc...

Comment: @James111 You can override the deployment key for different environments by providing options when you wrap a component. See here: https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push#plugin-usage#user-content-dynamic-deployment-assignment

Answer (score 1):

So basically deployment keys can be stored in different locations and it depends upon how you have configured the application.

You can always find what is the location of the deployment key the following way:

1) For *Android* it is injected in MainApplication.java file -> getPackages method (the 1st parameter for CodePush class constructor).
By default it should be `R.string.reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey` which points exactly to `strings.xml` file. You can override this if needed and store deployment key in arbitrary place or simply hard-code it here (though it is not recommended).

2) For *iOS* the default place to store deployment key is `Info.plist` file located in iOS folder of the application (entry named **CodePushDeploymentKey**).
Later it is extracted by the app in native module in `CodePushConfig.m` class.